# How to draw a circle with a radius of 100m in mapkit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I need to draw a circle around the user location as shown in this [image](http://www.highoncoding.com/articleimages/mapkit_002.png). i understand that the circle is drawn by default, but what i want to do is to draw a circle with 100 meter radius. how can I do that?

Comment: This discussion may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056451/draw-a-circle-of-1000m-radius-around-users-location-in-mkmapview I have not tried it but it is something what u want.